# Which WCF binding is preferred when the client and server are on different machine or locations but need to run under the same domain servers?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I have looked at the msdn article that explain the properties of different WCF bindings, but when I came across questions like the one I have posted I don't really get the answer about which binding to use in specific scenarios.

I have my client a web application located in Bangalore, India on intel.com domain/network and now I have my WCF service hosted in Seattle, US again on intel.com domain/network. Which WCF binding is the best choice for communication between client and server?

Comment: Check out the [WCF Binding Decision Tree](http://prasadhonrao.com/wcf-binding-decision-tree/) for your answer

Comment: Thanks this will  certainly help, however detailed explanation would be great. Like why named pipe is used for cross server situations etc, what features named pipe provide to facilitate that.

Answer (score 0):

If application and service are hosted on same network in different location the type of binding which you need to use depends on other factors.
E.g transaction support, support for encoding, data volume etc